# How can i replicate NgFor directive in Nativescript core?

Tags: nativescript

I'm looking to find a way to using some kind of template in Nativescript Core.

I discover that Nativescript Angular got a NgFor directive, which allows to render templates.

Is there a way in Nativescript Core to do something like that?

```
<StackLayout *ngFor="let fruit of fruitList" class="list-group-item">
   <Label [text]="fruit"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/ng-directives#ngfor-directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We call it [Repeater](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/repeater) on NativeScript Core.

```
<Repeater items="{{ items }}">
    <Repeater.itemsLayout>
        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" />
    </Repeater.itemsLayout>
    <Repeater.itemTemplate>
        <Label text="{{ $value }}" margin="10" />
    </Repeater.itemTemplate>
</Repeater>
```